# C# / I fill up a DataGridView from a string array by picking the next cell randomly and do not want to pick used cell again

Tags: c#, arrays, random, datagridview

I have a string array and have to fill up a DataGridView with it by picking a random next cell. I want to use all items of the array but avoid to pick a cell I already filled up. It is fine if there are empty cells but I have to use all items.

What I tried:

```
foreach (var item in myarray)
        {
            y = random.Next(0, 5);
            x = random.Next(0, t.Rows.Count);
            t.CurrentCell = t[y, x];

            for (int j = 0; j < t.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                
                for (int k = 0; k < t.Rows.Count; k++)
                {
                   
                    if (t.Rows[k].Cells[j].Value == null)
                    {
                        t.CurrentCell.Value = item;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: This question will almost certainly be locked, but here's the answer - construct a List of all possible cell locations and then iterate through the string array once, randomly choosing the target cell from the location list and then removing it. The location list could be a list of (x,y) tuples for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a number to each cell from left to right, like for 4x4 matrix each cell will be numbered from 0 to 15. After that you can shuffle `0...15` array of integers and iterate over that array by assigning a string to the corresponding cell which you can get by converting a number from array (cellNumber) back to coordinates like this:
`(cellNumber / rowsCount, cellNumber % columnsCount)`.

Consider following source code:

```
private static Random rng = new Random();  

public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}

public static (int x, int y) GetCoordinates(int cellNumber, int rowsCount, int columnsCount) {
    return (cellNumber / rowsCount, cellNumber % columnsCount);
}

public static void Main()
{
    var rowsCount = 4;
    var columnsCount = 4;
    var cellNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0,rowsCount*columnsCount - 1).ToList();
    cellNumbers.Shuffle();
    foreach (var cellCoordinates in cellNumbers.Select(x => GetCoordinates(x, rowsCount, columnsCount))) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{cellCoordinates.x},{cellCoordinates.y}");
    }
}
```